# What is payloadRevision in axon server stored payload?

Tags: axon

I'm playing around with axon server and have connected a dummy project to the server. While browsing the events on the server, I saw the field `payloadRevision` and couldn't find any information on what that meant?

My best guess is that would ordinarily store the the event version number, but I wasn't sure how to test this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `payloadRevision` field stores the "version" of the event that was stored in AxonServer. Clients can provide a version number to make the task of upcasting more efficient. This is the case when the structure of events changes over time.

There is a chapter on Event Upcasting in the Axon Framework reference guide: https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-versioning

The default value of the revision is empty. Once the structure of an event changes, it is recommended to put a value in there, which the upcasters can recognize. The first upcaster would take the empty revision and convert the structure to whatever structure was next.

Comment: Thanks Allard. Just out of curiosity. Why is it recommended to not default the revision to 1 or 0 to start with?

Comment: The most important thing is that when you make your first structural change, that you can configure your upcaster with a combination of payloadFype and revision to trigger the transformation. In the end, which value that is for the first time doesn’t really matter. Since Axon doesn’t have an ‘opinion’ on whther revision should be a number, a semantic version, ‘null’ seemed a sensible default